# How to make different tabs with same user but different windows with different users using localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm developing chat application and I managed to set same user across different opened tabs but across different windows I want to allow different users.

`client.js`:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    if (typeof(localStorage.localStor) === "undefined") {
        console.log("is null");
        localStorage.setItem('localStor', {});
        //user displayed for registering 
    } else {
        console.log("exists");
        console.log(typeof(localStorage.localStor)); //prints 'string'
        //display as already registered user
    }
}, false);
```

So when user registers in a tab in one window ,after that, all the tabs opened in this window are for the same user ,but when opening new window the user registered in the first one will appear as registered also here.

I've read that by using session ,new tabs have a session one for each,so I don't think it is preferable.

How can I achieve that in `JavaScript` without JQuery? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think about Facebook, Google, SO even... You basically can't have multiple users running in the same browser (except for non-incognito / incognito mode). All data is shared between tabs and windows and are domain-bound. The only difference between a tab and a window is the way they are presented to the user.

Comment: As others have pointed out tabs are nothing but windows grouped together. Most modern browsers allows you to rip a tab to separate window and vice versa. So, you can either choose to have multiple users across tabs or same user across all windows.

Answer (score 0):

As far as javascript is concerned, all tabs are separate windows. Your browser just displays tabs together for convenience. You can either use localStorage to keep a user persistent through all windows/tabs or sessionStorage to keep a user persistent only in one specific window/tab.